# Does throwing an HttpsError() in a Firebase Callable Function cause the execution status of the function in Cloud Monitoring to be "error"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-monitoring

Having a Firebase Callable Function, for "handled" errors (not exceptions) occurring during execution, I `throw new HttpsError(...)`'s to notify the client that an error occurred and handle them appropriately.

For monitoring the healthiness of the Cloud Functions, I'm using Google Cloud Monitoring. Therefore I wanted to set up an alert that alerts based on the following query *if something really goes wrong (unhandled exception, whatever other errors could occur during function execution)*:

[image: Cloud Monitoring query for Cloud Function errors]

What I want to have is exception alerting - so if a Cloud Function fails because during an execution an uncaught exception gets thrown, I want to be alerted.

But I do *not* want this alert to fire if I intentionally "return" (throw) this special `HttpsError` which is thrown in cases of misuse or "handled" errors (like authentication failure):

```js
throw new HttpsError('permission-denied', 'Access denied')
```

My question is now whether Cloud Functions that `throw HttpsError(...)` count as `status = "error"` or if they count as `status = ok` in Cloud Monitoring.

My feeling is they count as `error` (as the alert fires sometimes) but if I then look in the Firebase Console's Function log, they do not show up as error there. So they do not have the red exclamation mark:
[image: Firebase Console Functions Log Exclamation mark]

Instead there, the log just says something like `...finished with status code: 204`
That's what makes me wonder if an `error` in Cloud Monitoring is just every function that ended with "Http Status code != 200"

If throwing an HttpsError does count as error, how could I query only functions that crashed/did not execute as intended for my alert?